# usb sound card no sound with putty

Tags: audio, putty

I am trying to configure my USB sound card for use on the pi.
With the graphical interface, I can change the sound card and output the sound to the USB card.

Without the graphical interface with Putty (no screen in HDMI), the sound does not come out of the USB card.
I modified this in the `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` file:

```
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
```

Do you know how can I solve this problem?[image: aplay]

Comment: "1" might not be the USB card. Please check `cat /proc/asound/cards` See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/80075/19949

Comment: ... and please post output of text commands as text, not as screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have created a new user, `sgl`. This user must be in the `audio` group to use audio devices with only a remote login. Furthermore, you may have to [remove](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/122426/33476) the `pi` user from that group, as having several users with exclusive access to audio hardware can create conflicts.